# change device port appium

Tags: port, device, appium

How to start appium server from windows using command line, where I can specify device port also? I tried from Appium server GUI, eventhough I am using different port for running two appium server, I guess device port used by both server are same. Whenever I run appium script, it runs on only one device. I have created 2 instances of android driver. Any work around from GUI also fine. Please help

Answer (score 3):

Ways to Start Appium server

**1. Programatically**

```
 CommandLine command = new CommandLine("cmd");

  command.addArgument("/c");
  command.addArgument("C:/AppiumForWindows-1.3.4.1/Appium/node.exe");
  command.addArgument("C:/AppiumForWindows-1.3.4.1/Appium/node_modules/appium/bin/appium.js");
  command.addArgument("--address");
  command.addArgument("127.0.0.1");
  command.addArgument("--port");
  command.addArgument("4724");
  command.addArgument("--no-reset");
  command.addArgument("--log");
  command.addArgument("D:/appiumLogs.txt");
  DefaultExecuteResultHandler resultHandler = new DefaultExecuteResultHandler();
  DefaultExecutor executor = new DefaultExecutor();
  executor.setExitValue(1);

  try {
   executor.execute(command, resultHandler);
  } catch (IOException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
  }
```

**2. Command line**

command: `D:\Appium\node.exe D:\Appium\node_modules\appium\lib\server\main.js --address 127.0.0.1 --port 4723 --no-reset --platform-name Android --platform-version 23 --automation-name Appium --log-no-color`

**3. From Appium GUI**

Please refer [this](http://happyautomation.blogspot.nl/2015/01/how-to-start-stop-appium-server.html) link for more information.

You can start multiple sessions on different ports on same server. While creating a session change ports e.g. `driver = new AndroidDriver<MobileElement>(new URL("http://serverAddress + ":" + serverPort+ "/wd/hub"), capabilities);`